# How to view plotly dash interactive table in nbviewer or github?

Tags: python, html, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have code that creates an interactive table using `dash` - I do this in Juypterlab and the code works just fine for me to view and interact with the table in Juypterlab, but when I upload the ipynb notebook to github and look at the notebook in nbviewer the table no longer loads and I get an error that says `Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.`

If I try firefox browser I get an error that says

```
An error occurred during a connection to 126.2.3.3:8054. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Trying with browers google chrom and brave also give similar errors saying `Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.`

I'm having trouble finding the setting I'm missing to make the table viewable - is there a `dash` setting I'm missing? Do I need to make the `8054` port accessible somehow or is it an extension in my web browser causing the problem?

The code I have that makes the dash table looks like this

```
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

X_interactive = data

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-interactivity',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in X_interactive.columns
        ],
        data=X_interactive.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable="single",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=True,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    ),
    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity', 'style_data_conditional'),
    Input('datatable-interactivity', 'selected_columns')
)
def update_styles(selected_columns):
    return [{
        'if': { 'column_id': i },
        'background_color': '#D2F3FF'
    } for i in selected_columns]

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity-container', "children"),
    Input('datatable-interactivity', "derived_virtual_data"),
    Input('datatable-interactivity', "derived_virtual_selected_rows"))
def update_graphs(rows, derived_virtual_selected_rows):

    if derived_virtual_selected_rows is None:
        derived_virtual_selected_rows = []

    dff = X_interactive if rows is None else pd.DataFrame(rows)

    colors = ['#7FDBFF' if i in derived_virtual_selected_rows else '#0074D9'
              for i in range(len(dff))]

    return [
        dcc.Graph(
            id=column,
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": dff["Gene"],
                        "y": dff[column],
                        "type": "bar",
                        "marker": {"color": colors},
                    }
                ],
                "layout": {
                    "xaxis": {"automargin": True},
                    "yaxis": {
                        "automargin": True,
                        "title": {"text": column}
                    },
                    "height": 250,
                    "margin": {"t": 10, "l": 10, "r": 10},
                },
            },
        )
        # check if column exists - user may have deleted it
        # If `column.deletable=False`, then you don't
        # need to do this check.
        for column in ["col1", "col2", "col3"] if column in dff
    ]

    
app.run_server(mode='inline', port=8054)
```

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers?

Comment: Just tried in google chrome and it comes back with ```126.2.3.3 sent an invalid response.``` A link to the code I am trying to view in nbviewer can be found here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/hlnicholls/test/blob/main/Interactive_SHAP.ipynb

Comment: `mode='inline'` is required only while using JupyterDash. `plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()` alone is sufficient for inline visualization here. Also rename your dash instance `app = dash.Dash(__name__)`

Comment: Also, when I am going to the notebook provided, it says that the source for the Frame where the graph should be is `8062` and not `8054`

Comment: Thank you for this, when I remove ```mode=inline``` and just have ```app.run_server(port=8054)``` the dash table is only viewable in another tab and not the notebook itself. Originally I tried adding ```plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()``` to help with viewing the notebook online - should I just be sticking with ```mode='inline'``` if I want the table to be viewed in the notebook? Also for the ```8064``` I may be misunderstanding how to re-use it but, when I re-run it locally the port becomes busy/gives a in-use error, so I've been changing the number for a new port so I can see the table.

Comment: when I ran an app on that port and tried to view it through the notebook (which I assume should be good enough to try and reproduce the problem), I noticed when I went into the page source, (tapped with 2 fingers and clicked view page source), and changed the source from HTTPS to HTTP, it seemed to actually show the page source. I think this is the reasoning behind the SSL error since the localhost uses `http` and not `https`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839987/how-to-add-a-ssl-certificate-to-a-dash-app somwthing like this may end up helping solve the issue, since you can add an SSL certificate to the dash app, so far, I haven't been able to find much for fixing it directly on nbviewer.